# Android PRL update

Tags: android

Would it be possible to do this programatically? So far we are opening the dialer and dialing *228... but would prefer another method. Any ideas, or possible other directions?

Comment: Maybe you should take a moment to learn more about the [PRL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_Roaming_List).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my research, the Android has classes to handle the upload of PRL using OTAUtils. However each phone manufacturer has different process to update the phone dependent on chipset.

You would have to service unlock phone and write the new PRL values.

There simply does not appear to be any general API to write PRL to phone.